Agregar barra horizontal con color de fondo y transparencia a un video usando ffmpeg
estoy subiendo videos utilizando ffmpeg. A los videos le agrego un texto como marca de agua pero lo que deseo es que el texto este situado dentro de una barra horizontal o rectangulo que ocupe todo el ancho del video y que dicha barra tenga un color de fondo con una transparencia de ser posible(background-color).
He intentado buscando una solución pero aún no he encontrado alguna
Aquí está mi código:
$command = "$ffmpeg -i $ruta_video -s $resolucion -vf drawtext=\"fontfile=fuente/Roboto-Regular.ttf: text='miwebsite.com': fontcolor=0x312419: fontsize=$tamano_fuente: shadowcolor=0xF4DFBA: shadowx=2: shadowy=2: x=((w-text_w) / 2): y=((h*90) / 100)\" videos/video_1.mp4";

Estoy usando PHP como lenguaje backend y el texto que es la marca de agua es: miwebsite.com
Ese texto lo deseo dentro de un rectángulo con un color de fondo con transparencia que ocupe todo el ancho del video como indique líneas arriba.
Muchas gracias por sus sugerencias.

Para agregar una barra horizontal con color de fondo y transparencia que ocupe todo el ancho del video, puedes usar el filtro drawbox de FFmpeg junto con drawtext.
Comando:

$command = "$ffmpeg -i $ruta_video -s $resolucion -vf " 
drawbox=x=0:y=(h0.9):w=w:h=50:color=black@0.5:t=fill, 
drawtext=fontfile='fuente/Roboto-Regular.ttf': 
text='miwebsite.com':fontcolor=white:fontsize=$tamano_fuente: 
x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h0.9)+(50-text_h)/2" \ videos/video_1.mp4";

lo que hace drawbox:

x=0: La barra comienza desde el borde izquierdo del video.
y=(h*0.9): La barra se posiciona al 90% de la altura del video (ajusta este valor según tus necesidades).
w=w: La barra ocupa todo el ancho del video.
h=50: Altura de la barra (puedes ajustar este valor).
color=black@0.5: El color de la barra es negro con un 50% de transparencia (@0.5 define la transparencia).
t=fill: La barra se rellena completamente (sin bordes).

Yo uso esto para tutoriales, espero que te sirva.
Documentacion: https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#drawbox
